# How can I get context from dart file

Tags: flutter

I have this dart file `category_data.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final List categories = [
  'Entertainment',
  'Sports',
  'Politics',
  'Science',
  'Technology',
  'Travel'
];
/*
  you can change your category here.
  If you change, make sure you have changed in the admin panel.
  Otherwise the app will show error.
*/

/*
  if your change the defalut category, make sure your category item munber is equal to category colors item number.
  Example: If you have 5 categories, then remove an color item in the category colors.
  else if you have more than 6 categories, then you have to add color items in the category colors List down below.
*/

final List categoryColors = [
  Colors.orange[200],
  Colors.blue[200],
  Colors.red[200],
  Colors.pink[200],
  Colors.purple[200],
  Colors.blueGrey[400]
];
```

I want to add internationalization through intl plugin. For this I am using the follow code to get the locale translation of text:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).categoryName
```

Then categories list would be the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news_app/generated/l10n.dart';

final List categories = [
  AppLocalizations.of(context).entertainment,
  AppLocalizations.of(context).sports,
  AppLocalizations.of(context).politics,
  AppLocalizations.of(context).science,
  AppLocalizations.of(context).technology,
  AppLocalizations.of(context).travel
];
```

But this code give me an error, because I don't have the context:

```
Undefined name 'context'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name
```

How could you get the context to use internationalization? I have only seen the context in the build method of the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method and pass the context to it.

```
    List _getCategoryList(BuildContext context) {
    return  [
             AppLocalizations.of(context).entertainment,
             AppLocalizations.of(context).sports,
             AppLocalizations.of(context).politics,
             AppLocalizations.of(context).science,
             AppLocalizations.of(context).technology,
             AppLocalizations.of(context).travel
     ];
}
```

You can use it like:

```
final List categories = _getCategoryList(context); -- Use this inside your widget.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before, the way i resolved it is to create a `GlobalKey`:

```
static GlobalKey rootWidgetKey = GlobalKey();
```

Then attach it to your root widget:

```
...
home: YourRootWidget(
  key: rootWidgetKey,
  ...
```

Then you can access the `root` context anywhere by referring to `rootWidgetKey.currentContext`.

Answer (score 1):

add your list after the build method like the example

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final List categories = [
 AppLocalizations.of(context).entertainment,
 AppLocalizations.of(context).sports,
 AppLocalizations.of(context).politics,
 AppLocalizations.of(context).science,
 AppLocalizations.of(context).technology,
 AppLocalizations.of(context).travel
 ];
 return ...
```